# How often Google AMP Cache will be updated if no one visit a page?

Tags: amp-html

In Google AMP documentation, it says "Each time a user accesses AMP content from the cache, the content is automatically updated, and the updated version is served to the next user".

Then what if a content of a AMP page is updated but no one visits the page for few days? Will it be updated after certain amount of time passed?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - it won't. Only once someone visited the page, due to the AMP caches one-behind-caching strategy.